# Trigger change of image after dropping three objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, drag-and-drop, dom-events

After dropping the top three boxes onto the car, I would like to change the car image.

Does anyone know a way where I can specify after all the boxes are dropped it triggers an event to change the car image?

HTML code for car  image

```
<div id="car">
<img name="car" src="http://www.danconveys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/car-complete_1.png" width="440" height="154" alt="">
</div>

 #car {
 position:absolute;
 left:46px;
 top:160px;
 width:430px;
 height:128px;
 z-index:7;
 }
```

Here is the image that I want it changing to: 
http://www.danconveys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/car_break.png

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dantest2014/9JTSQ/12/

Hope that someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle looks almost correct. The two things you still need to do are (1) count the number of boxes dropped, and (2) trigger the new image.

Just add a counter to your `drop` function:

```
var NUM_BOXES = 4,
    dropped = 0;
function drop (event, ui) {
    if (++dropped === NUM_BOXES) {
        $('#car > img').attr('src', '.../car_break.png');
    }
}
```

One thing that may be a typo in your current jsfiddle, you're setting the `src` attribute on `#car`, but the image is *inside* that element. I've fixed that with the `#car > img` selector above.